# H5 Hexadecimal data

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, hdf5, h5py

When I load a .h5 file into the spyder environment using h5py, I no longer see the hexadecimal data that was in the original file.

Does Python convert the hex information to uint8 automatically?

Comment: What does you see?  Without a sample file to test, or guidelines on how to create one, I don't think we can help you.

Comment: How do you 'see' hexadecimal data?  With a utility like `h5ls`?

Answer (score 1):

HDF5 does not store hexadecimal data, only numbers and characters. The [documentation of HDF5](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/PredefDTypes.html) lists the supported datatypes.

What you interpret as hexadecimal data is *very likely* integer data. You can have a look at the datatypes in your file by typing

```
h5dump -A filename.h5
```

The `-A` flag means: list the attributes (i.e. the metadata). You can look at a part of the file with

```
h5dump -A -g name_of_a_group filename.h5
```

Answer (score 0):

Python will probably convert those values to int32. 
Use hex() to see those values in hexadecimal form, and use bitwise operations for manipulation.
You can also use bin() to see things in binary

`hex(2)
'0x2'`